# Who should own the homebrew mysql data directory?

Tags: php, mysql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

My Mysql server 5.6.24 through homebrew has been running OK but during the day today I find that PHP and apache have lost connection with it even though I had entered in some records on the Sequel client app.

Poking around the local.err file I find the dreaded Server quit without updating PID file.

Looking around I followed the Yosemite answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624774/after-mysql-install-via-brew-i-get-the-error-the-server-quit-without-updating). It all seems like a permissions problem. As an aside, I thought part of the reason to use homebrew to install things like mysql is to eliminate the use of sudo, etc. Anyway the key command I did is this:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

which failed, both in running mysql.server start and mysql_safe &

The error that is reported is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/var/mysql/colorful.local.err: Permission denied
```

OK, never had that before. Looking around I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762543/mysql-what-user-should-own-usr-local-mysql-on-mac) and modified my command to this:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:wheel /usr/local/var/mysql/
```

with the same failure. So what could be going on? What should be the user:group? Or did I goof?

I notice that I also have a my.cnf file at /etc/mysql/my.cnf but the settings are commented out. It appears to be using the homebrew my.cnf file. It's something I'm not seeing, thx, sam

Comment: I don't know why it broke, but when I changed the ownership of /usr/local/var/mysql to myuserid:admin including the data directory, and restarted mysql, it went back to work. For me, using homebrew means to not change the ownership to _mysql.