# MySQL server flicking on and off

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I have installed MYSQL with homebrew and am accessing it via the client in system preferences. When I click "Start MYSQL Server" the only installed instance MySQL 8.0.14 goes from red to green becoming active, but only remains active for a few seconds before flicking back to inactive. This repeats continuously.

Additionally, within Sequel Pro I am able to create new databases and update them with the Query terminal however when trying to load my existing databases from my machine, the client shows an unexpected error message of and becomes completely unresponsive.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling to no avail. s

Starting MySQL from the command line with

```
    mysql.server start
```

Returns an error message of

```
    2019-03-08T17:38:36.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

I have tried killing all processes ([MacOS Can't start MySQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995912/macos-cant-start-mysql-server)) but the error remains.

Apologies if I am missing a glaringly onvious mistake, still quite new to MySQL!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `lsof -i :3306` might tell you what's running, but this is a question better suited for [Superuser](https://superuser.com) as it's related to your computer, not programming per-se.

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end? Or did you get an answer on Superuser you could link to? I have the same issue on macOS that's started all of a sudden. Very odd.