# Issues starting MySQL server Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, launchd

There are red dots, rather than green dots, next to "Active Instance" in the preference pane. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnnHO.png). When I click "Start MySQL Server" the lights flash green very briefly before turning red again. In other install tutorials (e.g. [this](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7019203#)), this doesn't happen.

However, when I try to use command line to start the server, with `sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` I get the line `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist: service already loaded Load failed: 37: Operation already in progress`. So it seems like some parts are already loaded.

When I try to launch MySQL (with `mysql -u root -p`), I get the error:
`dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTTNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE Referenced from: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0) Expected in: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib in /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql Abort trap: 6`

I get the same error when I try to do `mysql --version`.

Previously, I was getting the error `-bash: mysql: command not found`, but then I followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577374/mysql-command-not-found-in-os-x-10-7) and added the path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`. (Note that I still get the `-bash: mysql.server: command not found` when I try `mysql.server start`, so I don't know if the new path export fixed the problem altogether.) I re-installed MySQL from the DMG but still getting this error.

Additional information that may be relevant:
-I am on Mac OS X 11.6.5.
-I have uninstalled/re-installed MySQL several times
-I copied my.cnf and put it in the "Configuration File" spot in preferences, with the file path: `/private/etc/my.cnf`. This is also a part where it's possible I went wrong, since I don't exactly know what I'm doing; I just tried to follow directions from [here](https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/IMC/v7_3/5200-2696/content/466034749.htm), [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/macos-installation-prefpane.html) and used the actual code from [here](https://gist.github.com/juliandunn/7efc161ee2bec4801422d90bab24ad12). I also tried putting the my.cnf file in `/usr/local/mysql`, as some [other sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995912/macos-cant-start-mysql-server) seem to suggest. This did not work either.

Comment: Are you able to access the database using Oracle MySQL Workbench?

Comment: To make it easy, here is a link to the download
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: @easleyfixed Thank you, but when I tried to download it, it said "MySQLWorkbench cannot be opened because of a problem." And it's not the "unidentified developer" problem, because it doesn't show up in System preferences. Tried installing it again and didn't work. What would Workbench help with in this situation? Is it important to keep trying?

Comment: Because of a problem?  Hmm .. I wonder if there is something more going on than a database issue.  Did you make sure to download the right OS version?  I think it defaults to Windows on the drop down.

Comment: @easleyfixed yes I did install the Mac OS version, and it says it's for Big Sur and higher, which my Mac is. I appreciate your help, I wonder what else it could be besides database issue? I don't know if the Workbench download issues and the MySQL launch issues are related

Comment: They might not be, but it is curious coincidence.  Very interesting.

Comment: A test you could try is, if your Mac has Boot Camp or something like it, try to boot into a PC environment and try the same thing.  If it works then its a Mac thing, if it doesn't work, then its the DB/MySQL to blame.  At least get you pointed in the right direction perhaps.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't have Boot Camp and I have seen a lot of other videos where it works on Mac. So I think it's just something with my setup.

Comment: Oh of course, well hopefully you have some luck.

Comment: You probably have a higher chance of getting an answer if you post this question on SuperUser. This seems more a config/install issue then a programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: what I needed to do was uninstall MySQL and instead download an archived version of it--8.0.24 instead of the latest, 8.0.32, because it hadn't been compatible with my Mac version.